# Call .php file from .py file

Tags: php, python, sendmail

I currently have some JavaScript code that calls a .php file to send me an email from within a .jsp using an on-click function. It also includes a couple of variables, see below.

```
<script>
function sendMail(video, user) {
var xmlhttp;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else {// IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.mydomain.com/sendemail.php?video="+video+"&user="+user+'&ip=<%= request.getHeader("X-Real-IP") %>', false);
     xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Calling the script within a .jsp file:

```
            <a href="${videoUrl}" target="main" onclick="sendMail(parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('span')[2].attributes['title'].value, '${model.user.username}')">
```

Now I have a .py (different application than above) file that I would like to call this sendMail function. Section where I want to call the sendMail function in the .py file

```
def play(self, song_id):
    Addon.log('play: ' + song_id)
    if Addon.get_setting('transcode') == 'true':
        bitrate = self.bitrates[int(Addon.get_setting('bitrate'))]
        Addon.resolve_url(self.build_rest_url('stream.view', 
                                              {'id': song_id,
                                               'maxBitRate': bitrate}))
    else:
        Addon.resolve_url(self.build_rest_url('download.view', 
                                              {'id': song_id}))
```

Now is there anyway to accomplish this sendMail function but from within a python file? Instead of using the function can I call a URL?

I Frankenstein a webapp I'm running to email me notifications, easiest way I found was to create the JavaScript function and then call some PHP to send an email. Now the python is a different app all together, just trying to figure out how to do the same thing, call the URL to send an email but with Python.

Comment: I would throw in a bit of C++ too.

Comment: I know several Ruby scripts that you may want to include.

Comment: Seriously though, why are you using PHP, Python, AND Java for a webpage.  Why not pick one and use it?  Or is this copy and paste code that you are trying to Frankenstein together?

Comment: I Frankenstein a webapp I'm running to email me notifications, easiest way I found was to create the javascript function and then call some php to send an email. Now the python is a differnt app all together, just trying to figure out how to do the same thing, call the url to send an email but with python.

Comment: I cannot imagine this being the *easiest* way, but if you really think so, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a url try the [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) module  eg:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
>>> print f.read(100)
```

To send email try the [email module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html#module-email) starting with [any of these examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html).

To launch an external process on the same machine (eg the php script) try the [SubProcess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module

Answer (score 0):

Calling PHP code directly from Python code is not straightforward, but if I understand your situation correctly, all you really want to do here is send an HTTP request to a server, right?  And it just so happens that the server you are sending that HTTP request to is running a PHP application, but that's not relevant to your Python code at all?

Just `import urllib2`.  Construct the URL as a string (either in a similar manner to how the Javascript is doing it, or with more advanced functionality using a dictionary and `urllib2.urlencode()`).  Then `urllib2.urlopen(url)`.